# AngularJS ui.router abstract routes and trailing slashes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, states

I have three route states - an abstract state, a state that shows the listing and a state that specifically shows a detail of one particular object.

My states are configured as follows:

```
.state('movies', {
        url: "/movies",
        template: '<ui-view ng-show="isLoaded" />',
        abstract: true,
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            skip: true
        }
    })
    .state('movies.index', {
        url: "?genres&tags&year&season&page&perpage",
        templateUrl: "views/movies.html",
        controller: 'MoviesViewController',
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'Movies'
        }
    })
    .state('movies.show', {
        url: "/:id/:slug",
        controller: 'MoviesItemController',
        templateUrl: "views/movies/details.html",

        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            parent: 'movies.index',
            label: '{{item.title_main}}'
        }
    })
```

I'd like to add the posibility of movies.index also beginning with a slash, so the URL can either be /movies or /movies/. However with my design, I have no idea how to do that.

I'm also not sure if I understand the concept behind abstract states correctly. I can either use this, or have movies.index be the parent state, in which case, how do I replace its content by the child's template? Also, I have noticed that since the parent controller also gets called, an unnecessary GET request is sent to my API, which can slow things down (especially since it's completely useless information). Can anyone give me a hand in this?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this use case is supported by `$urlMatcherFactory.strictMode(false)`

Take a look her
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.$urlMatcherFactory#methods_strictmode